# Google Closure Compiler parse error: invalid property id for `css({float:'left'})`

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I'm using Google Closure Compiler application (command line interface). When I run it I get the below error.

```
deploy/js/Home.js:40: ERROR - Parse error. invalid property id
    this.$images.wrapAll('<div id="slideInner"></div>').css({float:'left'});
                                                                   ^

1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the key in quotes ? `.css({'float':'left'})` ?

Comment: Note that I've seen unquoted keywords used as this cause errors in IE, so it's a good thing to fix anyway :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that you need to do:

```
{'float':'left'}
```

This is because `float` is on the [list of Java keywords reserved by JavaScript](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm), so it cannot be used as a property name. This may no longer be an issue in newer JS engines, but it can be a problem in older ones, which is why the Compiler yields an error.

Comment: Are *Java* keywords really reserved in Ecmascript - I couldn't find a valid reference? Or is this a JScript issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have tons of soy files, and don't want to change everthing in every soy file, you can pass a flag to the compiler:

```
--compiler_flags="--language_in=ECMASCRIPT5"
```

It worked out well for me.