# Is the 'catch' method name of JS Promises/A+ invalid since it's a JS keyword?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-5

I started to use JS Promises in a project recently. I noticed that every time I use `.catch` my [JS linter](http://javascriptlint.com/) complains. It does run and does what it should but I looked up the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) and it really looks like it is right: Since [`catch` is a keyword](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.1) it can not be used as an identifier. As I understand method names are identifiers, so this is invalid:

```
Promise.reject("Duh").catch(alert);
```

It should be this instead:

```
Promise.reject("Duh")['catch'](alert);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: browsers that don't follow the ecmaScript spec might feel differently than those that do.

Comment: The linter likely complains because it tries to be ES3 compatible.

Comment: Related: [Browser support for using a reserved word as a property name in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5306315/218196) ... Kangax: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Reserved_words_as_property_names

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> What am I missing?

A property name is not an identifier, it can use any identifier name. From the spec on [Property Accessors](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1):

```
MemberExpression : MemberExpression . IdentifierName
CallExpression : CallExpression . IdentifierName
```

and [identifiers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6):

```
Identifier :: IdentifierName but not ReservedWord
```

You can use any arbitrary identifer name (but not things like integers) in a dot property access, but you can't use those that are [reserved] keywords as identifier, e.g. in a variable or function name.

However, this did change with ES5, back in [EcmaScript 3](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2) property names were required to be identiers. That's why you still need to use the bracket notation for keywords if you want to support legacy browsers; and it's the reason why your linter complains about it. [Same holds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12553171/1048572) for property names in object literals.

Comment: Not sure why it was downvoted, it's a correct answer. +1

Comment: well, it corrects a semantics issue with the question (about the word "identifier"), but it doesn't answer about why the warning or about IE8. (but i didn't downvote)

Comment: I downvoted because the original answer was a very poor, short answer that doesn't provide a lot of information. Removed the downvote though as subsequent edits were a lot better.

Comment: You are right. The key sentence is "An Identifier is an IdentifierName that is not a ReservedWord". +1

Comment: @Evert: Sorry, [you're right, and I'm ashamed of using this tactic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/183280) - only it just works too well. My intention was never to give an incomplete answer, though.

Comment: @Bergi: No need to say sorry to me ;) It seems like a bit of a waste of time to me to do this for virtual internet points, but I guess I simply have other means to entertain myself ;)