# Replacing the Q code with bluebird

Tags: javascript, promise, q, bluebird

I want to do some POC to replace my Q library code with bluebird,
after digging on the bluebird library I dont see (maybe i miss it) the **fail** method ,is it true? 
Does it have some similar logic (in BB) which I can consider to use,example will be helpful :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Q and Bluebird do have a `catch` method:

- https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisecatchonrejected
- http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html

which does about the same (being a shorthand for `.then(null, …)`). Since [`catch` is a keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25774628/1048572) and can cause syntax errors when used as a method name in pre-ES5 environments, both libraries do provide an alias. This alias is however different: `fail` for Q, and `caught` for Bluebird.

Answer (score 2):

Note that bluebird has a Q adapter written by bluebird's author called [bluebird-q](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird-q).

Like Bergi said, the way forward is not to use `fail` but to use `.catch` like native promises and bluebird.