# Import method on javascript object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found this in the keystonejs source code:

```
keystone.import('models');
```

Sublime text gives warning:

```
Expected an identifier and instead saw 'import' (a reserved word), Line 34, Column 8
```

Also, I searched the whole node module (keystonejs) and can't find import method defined. Can't find it on google either.

I know that the `import` is a new native feature in ES6, but I didn't know it could be a method of an object.

Is this a native method? Or is it defined by the module somewhere, and if it is, why can't I find it?

Comment: It may be wrongly complaining about a method name because "import" is a reserved keyword in Javascript.

Comment: I still don't get why I don't find it in the module directory. It has to be defined somewhere then, doesn't it?

Comment: related: [Is the 'catch' method name of JS Promises/A+ invalid since it's a JS keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25774628/1048572) - your tooling is faulty (or configured for ES3).

Answer (score 0):

[I found the definition](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/abc5e58f75cdac12e31cc24e3876e8650dee0448/index.js#L168). It was defined as

```
Keystone.prototype.import = ...
```

ST3 was wrongly complaining about a method name.

Comment: ST3 wouldn't do that on its own. Do you have JSHint or ESLint running as a package?