# Calling .finally via bracket notation

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

Working with legacy code, I stumbled upon such code:

```
this.User.updateRole(params)
    .then(this._onUserDismissingSetSuccess(), this.$alert.error)
    ["finally"](function () {
        this.isSendingData = false;
    });
```

and some other occasions with `["finally"]`.

Which made me scratch my head: what's the deal, why not `.finally()`? Is it some pattern, some trick or what?

Comment: not sure, maybe some broken old browsers don't like `.finally` (doubt it though) I've seen similar shenanigans with `["catch"]` in the past - I think

Comment: ```Promise``` is an object, which means you can access it using ```Dot property accessor``` or ```Square brackets property accessor```.

Comment: Yeah, some linters (especially those that aren't handling es6+ code) I've found struggle to understand `.catch()` and `.finally()` as they think its part of a `try-catch-finally`

Comment: that was written by a PHP programmer indeed. git blame it

Comment: @silentmantra - how do you come by that bizarre theory?

Comment: @JaromandaX I've seen that many times in the company I'm working now. Full stack PHP programmers use PHP object property syntax a lot... Also saw this in the past jobs. In the previous job that were Python programmers...

Comment: why would they do it for `finally` and not `then`?

Comment: @JaromandaX Because `then` is not a reserved keyword, unlike `catch` or `finally`.

Comment: oh, of course @Bergi - my PHP-foo is falling rapidly :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be *really* old code (or, code targeting really old browsers). Using keywords such as `finally` [or `catch`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25774628/1048572) with dot property access syntax was not supported in ES3. You had to quote these names in object literals and use bracket syntax when accessing these properties.